# JDK 8 with Myeclipse 10

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I would like to use  1.8 with Myeclipse 10.

And I installed JDK 8 and changed the Preferences to use jre8 but i am unable to change the compiler compliance level to 1.8 from inside Myeclipse , the properties dialog has a drop down that goes only up to 1.6. Restarted the tool but did not see any changes. Now what should i do to udate the JDK to 1.8 in Myeclipse

Thanks in adcance!!

Comment: You need something based on Eclipse Luna (4.4) to use Java 1.8, I think MyEclipse 10 is too old.

Comment: It's mentioned on the forums that it's MyEclipse 2014/2015 that supports java 8. MyEclipse 10 came out in 2012? Which preceeds Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this press release](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/11/meclipse-10), MyEclipse 10 was released in 2011 and is based on Eclipse Indigo. That is too old to work with Java 8, so you need a more recent version.

It is also mentioned in the [forum](https://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-30619.html) [discussions](http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-30269.html) that MyEclipse 2015 is the version that supports Java 8 out of the box , so you either need that one or you'd need to use custom update site to upgrade MyEclipse 2014. Since you have too old version already, you should probably go directly to 2015.